# Do I need to download the advanced warfare campaign?

Tags: xbox-360, call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

Please answer. I'm getting the game tomorrow so I would like soon answers. 
Another thing how much space do I need to play it including the havoc DLC when I only have 5.4 GB 
all together.

Comment: Download for what?  If you're buying the game, what do you expect you're downloading?

Comment: The campaign my friends told me id have to get it.

Comment: I'm getting th game from best buy

Comment: @Frank did my friends lie to me.

Comment: Every single game I've ever played that had a single player campaign, it comes on the disc.  There might be updates you need, but the base game should be playable just straight from the disc.

Comment: Thanks, if not I'll play bo2 untilIi figure it out

Comment: @Frank Grand Theft Auto V requires some data to be installed, but it's definitely not very common.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need to download the campaign because it comes on the disc, also I think you might have enough space for the dlc, if you don't then delete some games that you don't play anymore.